# How to get inside a setTimeout function using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Using Jest and Enzyme, how can I run the code inside the setTimeout()? I also want the delay time to be considered as 0 so it won't delay my test

function being tested:

```
   functionToBeTested = () => {
           //more code...
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('not logging :/')
              return 'anything';
            }, 1000);
    }
```

test:

```
it('functionToBeTested', () => { 
    expect(functionToBeTested).toEqual('anything');
})
```

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks Jest has builtin support for this.

Comment: just mock your setTimeout function

Answer (score 2):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export const functionToBeTested = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('not logging :/');
      resolve('anything');
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { functionToBeTested } from './';

jest.useFakeTimers();

test('should return correctly', async () => {
  const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  const promise = functionToBeTested();
  jest.runAllTimers();
  await expect(promise).resolves.toBe('anything');
  expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('not logging :/');
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56942805/index.spec.ts (8.036s)
  ✓ should return correctly (10ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    not logging :/

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.608s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56942805